# Non Commutative Multiplication

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to implement the axioms for geometric products of two vectors in n-dimensioned Euclidean vector space.

i.e Allowing the user to input the number of dimensions, for e.g 3

Generate e1,e2,e3 as symbols

Allow the user to input two vectors as functions of n-sized vectors eg a=a1e1+a2e2+a3e3; b=b1e1+b2e2+b3e3

where a1,a2... and b1,b2... are scalars

Expand the two vectors a and b

(a1e1+a2e2+a3e3)(b1e1+b2e2+b3e3)

It all works fine for me until this point.

From this point, I require the expansion operation to be non commutative, i.e e2e1=/=e1e2

Is there a way I can do this.

Following that, if the reader is feeling kind, is there a way to implement geometric algebra axioms such as e1e1=e2e2=enen=1

and e2e1=-e1e2
-> eiej=-ejei

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly: you want MATLAB to generate the code for your "expansion" (is it the cross product btw?) It is the other way around: you need to tell MATLAB how to perform the operation. But again, maybe I din't understand the question...

Comment: @CST-Link Hi! I'm trying to get (a1e1+a2e2+a3e3)(b1e1+b2e2+b3e3) to expand to a1b1e1e1+a1b2e1e2+a1b3e1e3+a2b1e2e1+a2b2e2e2+a2b3e2e3+a3b1e3e1+a3b2e3e2+a3b3e3e3

Comment: @CST-Link Or to clarify further I would like to expand (a+b+c)(a+b+c) where ab=/=ba

Comment: But isn't that made sure by the fact that e1e2 ≠ e2e1?

Comment: Also, you want to do that symbolically? Or numerically?

Comment: @CST-Link Yes, I would just like some help implementing a function which expands 2 vectors where e1e2 ≠ e2e1. I would like to do it symbolically. i.e noncommexpand([a+b],[a+b]) would return a^2+ba+ab+b^2

Comment: How about aa + ab + ba + bb? Because, if you accept it like this, is easy.

Comment: Yes that would be wonderful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'd like is a "multiplication" that enumerates all the pairs (T1, T2) where T1 is a term from the first expression, and T2 is a term from the second term.

```
function C = pairwise_mul(S1, S2)
         % ' S1, S2 are cell  arrays '
         N1 = numel(S1);
         N2 = numel(S2);
         C = cell(1, N1*N2);

         for k1 = 1:N1
                 for k2 = 1:N2
                         k    = k2 + N1*(k1-1);
                         C{k} = [S1{k1} S2{k2}];
                 end;
         end;
end
```

You can invoke it like this:

```
expr1  = {'a1', 'b1', 'c1'};
expr2  = {'a2', 'b2' };
result = pairwise_mul(expr1, expr2);
```